# ASIHTTPRequest video download failed sometimes and sometimes not?

Tags: ios5, asihttprequest

In my project i need to download nearly 50 videos from cloud, i download it using ASIHTTPRequest in Asynchronous way by handling responses using success and failure delegate methods.

When video download is success the corresponding success delegate method is called and i got status code 200, if partial download i got status code 206 in same delegate method and if file not found i got status code 404 on success delegate method.

If request itself failed it hit the corresponding failure delegate method, some times it return status code 200 in failure delegate method. But status 200 for success only.

Another thing i need to make video download complete without any failure(How can i handle this).If any one knows help me out.

Thanks